# How can I get SQL query result rows as columns with different header names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

| Sales Type Name | Sales Type |
| --- | --- |
| Cash | 500 |
| Visa | 1200 |

This how I would like my results to look like:

| cash | visa |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 1200 |

Comment: What if you have more than two rows? Do you want the sum of the values? The highest value?

Comment: I use SQL Server , And I Want the summation of rows with same Sales Type

Comment: Please follow the standard PIVOT examples and post back here if you have an actual question, not just "please do this for me", try something like this: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [Cash], [Visa]
FROM (
   SELECT SalesTypeName, SalesType
   FROM t
)  src
PIVOT
(
   SUM (SalesType)
   FOR SalesTypeName IN ([Cash], [Visa])
) pvt
```

If you have more cases of `SalesTypeName` you can easily extend the query by adding the values in the `FOR` clause of the `PIVOT`. For a dynamic number of values you have to use dynamic `PIVOT`.

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/846920/7)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when sales_type_name = 'Cash' then Sales_Type end) as cash,
       sum(case when sales_type_name = 'Visa' then Sales_Type end) as visa    
from t
```